# What is the benefit of writing an object to a file?

Tags: java, file, object, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I understand we can do this with file input and output, but why would we want to do this?

Comment: *"Is it so we can load it in without having to create a new object every time we want to use it?"* - No, you still need to create a new instance of the object in order to load it's properties. The main reason you want to save an object is so you can persist the data between runs. You might also need to share data between difference processes as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply called *[persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science))*.

You nailed it: you want to be able to store information (for example *after* intensive computations) in a way that survives the lifetime of the current [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)).

In that sense [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) is a (poor) version of database storage.

But of course, that comment is correct: this does not prevent the creation of objects. It is a mechanism to resurrect previous state into "new" objects.

Comment: Thank you! This explained it well.